# jQuery loop selecting the last item and not adding items correctly

Tags: jquery

I have an else statement which triggers a particular loop, 3 drop downs one with a list of publishers, one with a list of authors one with a list of years (all dependent on each other).  When i select a publisher and then 'all authors' it triggers the first loop which doesnt work.  When i select a publisher and then an author it triggers the second loop, which does work.  I'm trying to fix the first loop but cannot seem to get it working.

Instead of getting individual groups of data i just get a single one with all my authors in like this, unknown is the last item in my list so i guess the loop is just getting to the end of the list and using this for the originalGenre and bundling everything in it:

```
{
  "publisher": "Random House",
    "originalGenre": "Unknown",
      "authors": [{
        "author": "Stephen King",
        "publishedYear": [2008, 2012, 2013]
      }, {
        "author": "Mark Wallace",
        "publishedYear": [2010]
      }, {
        "author": "Will Chambers",
        "publishedYear": [2010, 2013]
      }, {
        "author": "Sally Bernstein",
        "publishedYear": [2014]
      }, {
        "author": "Richard Burns",
        "publishedYear": [2014]
      }]
}
```

What i'd expect is something like:

```
"publishers": [{
  "publisher": "Random House",
  "originalGenre": "Horror",
  "authors": [{
    "author": "Stephen King",
    "publishedYear": [2008, 2012, 2013]
  }, {
    "author": "Mark Wallace",
    "publishedYear": [2010]
  }]
}, {
  "publisher": "Random House",
  "originalGenre": "Biography",
  "authors": [{
    "author": "Will Chambers",
    "publishedYear": [2010, 2013]
  }, {
    "author": "Sally Bernstein",
    "publishedYear": [2014]
  }]
}, {
  "publisher": "Random House",
  "originalGenre": "Unknown",
  "authors": [{
    "author": "Richard Burns",
    "publishedYear": [2014]
  }]
}]
```

My code for this is:

```
var newObj = {
  'publisher': publisher,
  'originalGenre': "",
  'authors': []
};

if (author == '') {
  for (i = 0; i < data.genres.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < data.genres[i].publishers.length; j++) {
      var originalGenre = data.genres[i].publishers[j].originalGenre;
      if (data.genres[i].publishers[j].publisher == publisher) {
        newObj.authors = newObj.authors.concat(data.genres[i].publishers[j].authors);
        newObj.originalGenre = originalGenre;
        break
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the code which works as expected when i select a specific Author and select 'all years' so really i just need to copy this code and apply is to the 'all authors' section, all i need to do i define an author somewhere in the loop i think?

```
else {
  var newAuthor = {
    'author': author,
    'publishedYear': []
  };

  if (year == '') {
    for (i = 0; i < profileData.genres.length; i++) {
      var originalgenre = profileData.genres[i].genre;
      for (j = 0; j < profileData.genres[i].publishers.length; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < profileData.genres[i].publishers[j].authors.length; k++) {
          if (profileData.genres[i].publishers[j].authors[k].author == author) {
            newAuthor.publishedYear = profileData.genres[i].publishers[j].authors[k].publishedYear;
            newObj.originalgenre = originalgenre;

          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  newObj.authors.push(newAuthor);
}
```

So these two sections of code are all together, if all authors are selected it executes the first piece of code, if an author is selected it takes the value of the drop down assigned the an 'author' variable and assigns it to a 'newAuthor' variable and then moves on to get the years.  It then pushes it into the main new obj.

Any ideas how i can replicate the working functionality of the second piece of code in the first piece?

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately i'm using IE8 and cannot get on jsFiddle, just wont render at all

Comment: @Hagbard I suggest having more than one browser to hand when doing web development. Doesn't take long to download and install chrome or firefox.

Comment: I'm not using my own computer, due to company policy i can only use IE8, it drives me crazy but nothing to be done

Comment: Forcing a developer to develop with only IE8 should be against their human rights! :)